# How to recreate working scrollspy example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I am trying to recreate a [really great scrollspy example](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/v6zhz/170/) from [a blog](http://www.codingeverything.com/2014/02/BootstrapDocsSideBar.html) but for some reason... I can't recreate it? I have tried copying and pasting the same code (*and* the external resources) into `Bootsnipp` and `JsFiddle` and I can't seem to recreate it. I am really confused as to what might be going on.

I' really appreciate if someone could recreate this issue, or if working source for this project could be reposted.

Comment: did you check the external references inside of that jsfiddle? You need to include 3 files to make it work. `bootstrap.js`, `bootstrap.css`, `font-awesome.css`. Try linking to their CDNs, I'd guess this is the issue.

Comment: Yup. I mean I got another scrollspy example working. I am just utterly confused at being unable to duplicate a working example. That's never happened to me before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external references in jsFiddle didn't list jQuery but it is needed. That was the only addition I had to make to get this functioning. Just add it before you add the `bootstrap.js`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Note that you don't really need jQuery - just change the JS portion of this include to use native JS and it would work without jQuery.

Working recreation:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/PGYJKB

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue.